# Juju boostrap for EC2 fails with access denied, but working credentials

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

To make a long story short, I'm using s3cmd to manipulate S3 buckets and have copied the access credentials over to my environments.yaml under a new "smlamazon" section, but this fails at bootstrap with access denied:

```
mitchy$ s3cmd ls
2013-11-08 18:49  s3://sml-juju
2012-11-27 14:38  s3://sml-public
2013-05-27 15:45  s3://sml-website-backups
mitchy$ juju bootstrap --constraints "cpu-power=0 mem=512M" -v
verbose is deprecated with the current meaning, use show-log
2013-11-08 18:53:53 INFO juju.environs open.go:156 environment info already exists; using New not Prepare
2013-11-08 18:53:53 INFO juju.provider.ec2 ec2.go:193 opening environment "smlamazon"
2013-11-08 18:53:54 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 Access Denied
```

I essentially copied the "amazon" block and renamed it "smlamazon", and updated the access and secret keys (and s3 and admin secret) for it.

What am I missing?

Comment: For the record I did remember to switch environments :-)

Comment: Can you doublecheck to see if you have any files in `.juju/environments/`? I think blowing those away should fix your issue. (But not 100%)

Answer (score 1):

Juju requires access to control an S3 bucket and EC2 instances. If your access credentials were keys generated from AWS IAM this may mean you did not add the correct access group policy to your security credentials.  The following steps may be taken to grant this access key pair to provision your AWS infrastructure:

**Access the IAM control Panel**
[image: IAM control Panel - Add User]

**Obtain Access Key and Secret Access Key**
[image: IAM Control Panel - Keys]

**Select User and set Policy Template**
[image: IAM - Access Policy]

**Select EC2 Full Access and S3 Full Access**
[image: EC2 Full Access]
[image: S3 Full Access]
*Note* - If you are in a corporate environment, this may voilate access policy. You should check with your Administrator if you require segmented permissions to specific AZ's or custom access levels. This can be generated by your administrator, or by following the AWS IAM Policy tutorial.